# Uncaught Exception. could not find driver in docker container using sql server and base image php:7.3-apache

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, pdo, dockerfile

My docker file which is building successfully but in the time of login, getting this error "Uncaught Exception. could not find driver".

Application is using PDO extension for php to connect sql server.

```
FROM php:7.3-apache

# Env variables
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=y

# Install selected extensions and other stuff
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install apt-utils libxml2-dev gnupg apt-transport-https \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

# Install git
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install git \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

#Install ODBC Driver
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update

# Install sqlsrv
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg -i multiarch-support_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get -y install msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev
RUN pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv

# Install webapp extension
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    git libzip-dev libicu-dev\
    && docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install intl mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
RUN a2enmod rewrite

COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php
COPY . /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80/tcp
#EXPOSE 443/tcp
```

I have also added pdo extension entries for sqlsrv in my php.ini file

extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
extension=sqlsrv.so

Comment: Have you looked at the build logs for the container yet? It looks like you're pulling Microsoft packages for the wrong version of debian, i.e.: `docker run --interactive --rm --tty php:7.3-apache cat /etc/debian_version` returns `11.1`, not `9`.

Comment: so what should I change in my docker file